# How to add/Update key/values in dict in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, key

```
func exercise() {

    
    var stockTickers: [String: String] = [
        "APPL" : "Apple Inc",
        "HOG": "Harley-Davidson Inc",
        "BOOM": "Dynamic Materials",
        "HEINY": "Heineken",
        "BEN": "Franklin Resources Inc"
    ]
    
    
    stockTickers["WORK"] = ["Slack Technologies Inc"]
    stockTickers["BOOM"] = ["DMC Global Inc"]


  
     
    print(stockTickers["WORK"]!)
    print(stockTickers["BOOM"]!)
}
```

Error: Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to subscript of type 'String'

I do not understand the error, I'm new to swift, can someone guide me through this and tell mw why I see this error.

Comment: For reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alexander explained what you need to do in abstract terms. (Voted)

Specifically, change

```
stockTickers["WORK"] = ["Slack Technologies Inc"]
stockTickers["BOOM"] = ["DMC Global Inc"]
```

To

```
stockTickers["WORK"] = "Slack Technologies Inc"
stockTickers["BOOM"] = "DMC Global Inc"
```

The expression `["Slack Technologies Inc"]` defines a String array containing a single string. That's not what you want. you defined a dictionary of type `[String:String]`

If you wanted your dictionary to have String keys and values that contained arrays of strings, you'd have to change the way you declared your dictionary:

```
var stockTickers: [String: [String]] = [
    "APPL" : ["Apple Inc"],
    "HOG": ["Harley-Davidson Inc"],
    "BOOM": ["Dynamic Materials"],
    "HEINY": ["Heineken"],
    "BEN": ["Franklin Resources Inc"]
]
```

Answer (score 4):

`["DMC Global Inc"]` is an array literal containing a string. It evaluates to a value of type `[String]` (a.k.a. `Array<String>`).

Thus the error makes sense: you’re trying to a assign an array of strings in a place where only a String is expected.

Just remove the square brackets.